# c++ static non-static

Tags: c++, c, static, non-static

in c++
where are static or non-static variables stay? I mean in memory.

and, When are static or non-static variables initialized?

Need someone help me get my thought clear.
Thank you!

and what about C? same?

Comment: Maybe you will find some material in here interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162580/what-happens-when-a-computer-program-runs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They can go wherever the compiler (or linker or loader) wants to put them in memory, the C and C++ standards don't mandate that level of detail. They only mandate the *behaviour.*

Typically, static members are initialised once, either on program startup (including at compile time so that they're simply loaded in an already-initialised state) or immediately before first use.

Comment: Very well (and carefully) worded.

Answer (score 0):

Non static members residing place depends up on how the object is instantiated.

```
class foo
{
    int num ; // Non-Static member 
    // ....
};

foo obj ; // In this case `num` resides on stack. In fact, obj it self resides on stack
foo *temp = new foo;  // In this case `num` resides on heap or in memory location acquired from the free store.
```

I amn't sure about static members.

Answer (score 0):

Statics go in the same place as globals, which tends to be determined by the compiler, and are created when the program is loaded and persist until the program ends

Non-statics go where-ever you put them (on the stack or the heap)