# c++ variable visibility

Tags: c++

PLEASE READ THE SECOND EDIT FIRST.

I am looking for books or websites that explain in detailed the c/c++ memory management models.  One of the things I am trying to understand is:

```
namespace A {
    SomeClass A;
}
```

vs

```
namespace A {
    static SomeClass A;
}
```

vs

```
SomeClass A;
```

vs

```
static SomeClass A;
```

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
Sorry for the confusion, I mixed the concepts together, and asked the wrong questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162580/what-happens-when-a-computer-program-runs

Comment: Nothing to do with memory management - this is about name visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces allow to group entities like classes, objects and functions under a name. This way the global scope can be divided in "sub-scopes", each one with its own name.

You use keyword `using` to introduce a name from a namespace into the current declarative region.

For example:
without using namespace you will write:
    #include

```
int main () {
  std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

However you can also write:
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
int main () {
  cout << "Hello world!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

This allows you not to append napespace identifier before every

In C++ static class has no meaning unlike other OOP languages. You can have static data members methods.

Instead you can create:

1.A static method in class

```
class SomeClass
{
public:  static void myMethod(int x..)
    {
    }
}
```

2.Create a free function in namespace

```
namespace A 
{
    void myMethod(int x..)
    {
    }
}
```

Latter is better suited when you do not need an object. No class no object...

In both cases enclosing a class within namespace allows you to to group entities under a common name.

Comment: static SomeClass A; is a variable declaration instead of a class definition.

Answer (score 0):

First, namespaces are only known until compilation, after that they're non-existant. That said, your first half is no different from your second half in the final program, at least as far as I know. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Then, if both `static SomeClass A` and `SomeClass A` are at global scope (file level), then they're the same too.

Next, if both declarations are inside of a `class`, `struct` or function, then the `static` version will be put into the data segment of the executable too, while the non-`static` variant will be a normal stack variable.

Again, please, correct me if I'm wrong, but that's it as far as I know it.